# Adding depth to a box CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to add sides to a box div with CSS but can't seem to figure it out. This is what I have so far. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have included below the picture I am trying to replicate. It is the middle box.

[image: Box with depth that needs to be created]

```css
body {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #cc0000;
  margin: 50px;
}

.right-skew {
  position: relative;
}
.right-skew:before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -15px;
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  background: grey;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-10deg);
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}


.right-skew:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -15px;
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  background: grey;
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(10deg);
  transform: skew(10deg);
}

.skew-border {
 border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="box right-skew"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish this with borders pretty easily.

I'd put a large border around the left and right boxes and only color and left and right borders inversely.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box--1,
.box--3 {
  border: 20px solid white;
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
}

.box--1 {
  border-right-color: red;
}

.box--3 {
  border-left-color: red;
}

.box--2 {
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box box--1">1</div>
  <div class="box box--2">2</div>
  <div class="box box--3">3</div>
</div>
```

Here's a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/15k214am/3/

Some fun with transitions cause I'm bored: https://jsfiddle.net/15k214am/4/

Here's a small adjustment to allow the background color to show through: https://jsfiddle.net/15k214am/5/

Answer (score 7):

On either side, you need to add a couple of pseudo elements that are rotated with perspective added to the rotation transform.

```css
body {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #cc0000;
  margin: 50px;
}

/* following lines were added/modified */

.with-depth {
  position: relative;
}
.with-depth:before, .with-depth:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; /* no need to change */
  height: 100%; /* no need to change */
  width: 25px; /* can be changed depending on the required width */
  background: grey;
  z-index: -1; /* not really needed but will stop it from interfering with interation */
}
.with-depth:before {
  right: -25px; /* equal to -1 * width of pseudo-element */
  transform-origin: left; /* don't change */
  transform: perspective(10px) rotateY(10deg); /* can be changed as per need */
}  
.with-depth:after {
  left: -25px; /* equal to -1 * width of pseudo-element */
  transform-origin: right; /* don't change */
  transform: perspective(10px) rotateY(-10deg); /* can be changed as per need */
}

/* just for demo */
.box:hover{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box with-depth"></div>
</div>
```

Using this method would:

- produce a responsive output (try hovering the element in the demo) unlike the output that would be produced through the border method (*was referring to adding borders with pseudo-element on the middle one and not borders on the side elements like the other answer, which is very good*).
- leave the portion above and below the side elements transparent just in case the need is to show the background.
- let you have greater control over the angle of the depth.
- make it a little more easier to add extra effects like shadows etc to the box. Refer demo below. (*This point is not applicable for shape shown in question but would be useful for a generic one.*)

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #cc0000;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 2px #CCC;
}
.with-depth {
  position: relative;
}
.with-depth:before,
.with-depth:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  background: grey;
}
.with-depth:before {
  right: -25px;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: perspective(10px) rotateY(10deg);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 2px #CCC;
}
.with-depth:after {
  left: -25px;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: perspective(10px) rotateY(-10deg);
  box-shadow: -4px 4px 4px 2px #CCC;
}
/* just for demo */

.box:hover {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box with-depth"></div>
```